# How to pass data or add observer at onBackPressed event in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, observers, android-viewmodel

I'm developing android app and I'm facing problem with passing data when user pressed back button (which means onBackPress event is fired).
I wanted to fire event with observer with viewmodel but it doesn't work.
like this.

```
// First Fragment
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by bindViewModel()
viewModel.currencyVal.observe { state ->
    Timber.i("Event fired")
}
    ...

// Second fragment which was displayed with fragment transaction. This code is when user pressed back button. like override fun onBackPressed
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by bindViewModel()
viewModel.currencyVal(5)

// MyViewModel
    ...
val currencyVal = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    ...
fun setCurrencyVal(currencyVal: Int) {
    currencyVal.value = currencyVal
}
```

Here's bindViewModel function

```
protected inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> bindViewModel(
    crossinline initializer: T.() -> Unit = {}
): Lazy<T> = nonConcurrentLazy {
    ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity())
        .get(T::class.java)
        .also { it.initializer() }
}
```

And also passing data via fragment transaction doesn't work.

Could anyone please suggest how to pass data when user presses back button in FragmentActivity?

Thanks.

Comment: please add some more code for better understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am missing something. Is viewModel and firstViewModel the same object? Also if so are you sure that you are creating the ViewModel of the Activity, but not the Fragment?

```
 mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(YourViewModel.class);
```

Comment: That code is what i did to declear myViewModel. but i don't get observer event.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "that" code and "declare". If you mean my code it is not declaration. Here I create and instance. If you mean yours - you never confirmed how you create the ViewModel and the names just do not add up. Nor the method names nor nothing. How you directly call setValue(5), but then you have also:  fun setCurrencyVal(currencyVal: Int)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I created ViewModel class and used this ViewModel class in two fragments. I used `by` to create myViewModel variable. I updated my question

Comment: Could you please review?

Comment: Everything looks good. Just debug it. You can put logs in the init of both fragments with this reference. You can print also the VMs before yoiu call them so you can see that you are calling the same object. You can also print where you call setValue to check if you call it. And I am not sure how everything is working, but for example if the first fragment is removed if you replace it with the second fragment obviously it won't work. Also LiveData is lifecycle  aware. If the second Fragment is on top of the first you won't be called either. Print the lifecycle methods of Fragment 1.

Comment: I replaced Fragment 1 to Fragment 2(with fragmentManger.begintransaction.replace()....) . So you mean viewmodel observer doesn't work in this case? If so could you please tell me alternative solution?

Comment: Why you want to receive event in something that is gone?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200474/discussion-between-mobile-star-and-yavor-mitev).

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure your fragment instance is same.
If it's not same, you need to create view model by activity.
Hope this helps.